# Share Point Calendar time zone not correct

Tags: outlook, timezone

When importing a Share Point calendar into Outlook the time zone is incorrect.  Does the Outlook calendar time zone override Share Point?  The regional setting is PST but when importing the Share Point calendar into Outlook it converts to EST.

Is it not possible to have Outlook stick with Share Points regional setting(PST)?